# What's the performance differences between lookup then add vs just adding to a set

Tags: python, set

While using python set(), what's difference in performance between lookup+add versus add? which is preferred?

```
myset = set()
 for ...
     if key not in myset:
         myset.add(key)
```

and

```
myset = set()
 for ...
     myset.add(key)
```

Comment: The whole point of using a `set` is so that you don't have to care about adding duplicates. Either way, the performance difference is nil. They are both `O(1)` operations.

Comment: @dursk Post this as the answer!

Comment: and maybe use `myset.update()` instead of looping with a `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since checking membership is O(1) here, there is no (real) performance difference between the two, but there is a lot more clarity in the second version. The first just adds needless complexity to the algorithm.